# When using "Quadratic Collapse Edge Decimation" the faces number is not going down

Tags: meshlab

im following tutorials to simplify a mesh using Quadratic Collapse Edge Decimation filter, but the face count is not going down from the original number
why?
if you see my image i have hit apply many times and no reduction of faces occurs - what am i doing wrong?

[image: my settings]

Answer (score 1):

[QSLIM](http://mgarland.org/software/qslim.html) (the algorithm under `Quadratic Collapse Edge Decimation` filter) expects an almost-manifold surface to operate correctly.

It seems that your mesh does not represent such type of surface, where the number of faces is approximately twice the number of vertex. In your mesh the number of faces (97,082) is almost four times the number of vertices (24,947), so probably that mesh is not a planar surface, but a simplicial complex ( a mesh with triangles running inside of the external surface ) or it is a mesh with a really big number of duplicated faces.

Said that, I believe that the `preserve topology` and `preserve normal` flags are avoiding your mesh to be simplified, because collapsing any edge would make some features disappear. You can try to disable that flags, but I would like advise to question the process where that mesh was produced.

Also, try to clean your input mesh running `remove duplicate faces` filter before of the simplification.